# CMake add_library with future sources

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake file with two targets - `gen` and `lib2`. `lib2` depends on `gen`. The purpose of `gen`, which is custom target, is to take some interface description XML file and generate several C++ source and header files. I know what the result file names will be, but they don't exist yet at the time the CMake configuration is run.

Can I add them to the `lib2` library in `add_library`? Using simple list in `add_library` produces "Cannot find source file" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116872/creating-a-library-in-cmake-depending-on-source-files-not-available-when-generat).

The solution is to put the generator code into `create_custom_command`. Then have the `gen` target depend on the file that the aforementioned custom command generates. Then have `lib2` depend on `gen`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not possible to build and run gen separately first. Perhaps you could create empty files first (since you know the file names).

#### For example:

```
# Your gen custom target
add_custom_target ( gen ... )

# Create empty file with name source.cpp
file(WRITE source.cpp) # CMake 3.0-3.11
file(TOUCH source.cpp) # CMake 3.12+

# Create target lib2
add_library(lib2 STATIC source.cpp)

# Ensures gen is built before lib2
add_dependencies(lib2 gen)
```

Answer (score 0):

You add dependencies between targets using `add_dependencies`:

```
add_dependencies(lib2 gen)
```

Comment: I did that. Didn't help.

Comment: Then please post an [MCVE] . Without it, it's just guessing game.

Comment: Apologies. I've actually found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116872/creating-a-library-in-cmake-depending-on-source-files-not-available-when-generat). This question is thus a duplicate.